# Change font size and make text bolder in IPython.display Markdwon in JupyterLab notebook

Tags: markdown, jupyter-lab

Initially I have added heading to my **JupyterLab Notebook** using markdown cell:

```
<h1><center>For April 2021</center></h1>
```

then to make the date change dynamically I used Ipython.display Markdown:

```
m=Markdown("For {}".format(current_date))
m
For April 2021
```

I want to make the output look like markdown cell's output, with **larger font and bold text**.
I got this code from google, but I don't know how to combine it with the the already existing Markdown:

```
Markdown('<strong>{}</strong><br/>{}'.format(date_value)>)
```

How to make my output like the headings in markdown cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried some modifications, and it worked.
it can be done with single markdown object:

```
Markdown('<h1><center><strong>{}</strong><strong>{}</strong></center></h1>'.format('For ', MainDate))
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be further simplified.

If `MainDate` is a string:

`Markdown(f'<h1><center><strong>For {MainDate}</strong></center></h1>')`

If `MainDate` is a datetime (`%B` - Full Month; `%Y` - Full Year):

`Markdown(f'<h1><center><strong>For {MainDate.strftime("%B %Y")}</strong></center></h1>')`

Full Code:

```
from IPython.display import Markdown
from datetime import datetime
MainDate=datetime(2021, 4, 1)

Markdown('<h1><center><strong>{}</strong><strong>{}</strong></center></h1>'.format('For ', MainDate))
```

**For 2021-04-01 00:00:00**

```
Markdown(f'<h1><center><strong>For {MainDate}</strong></center></h1>')
```

**For 2021-04-01 00:00:00**

```
Markdown(f'<h1><center><strong>For {MainDate.strftime("%B %Y")}</strong></center></h1>')
```

**For April 2021**